# Suppressing tiny imaginary parts in complex numbers

Tags: core-language

How do I extract the real part of a substitution expression from `FindRoot` or `Solve`?  Or alternately, how do I insist that they return real results?

For example, `FindRoot` returns something of the form:

```
{x->A + B I}
```

Analytically, I know that `x` must be real.  Because `B` is 17+ orders of magnitude smaller than `A`, I assume it's numerical slop.

If I do:

```
Re[FindRoot[expr, {x, guess}]]
```

it simply returns:

```
Re[{x->A + B I}]
```

Assumptions aren't helping:

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], FindRoot[expr, {x, guess}]] ]
```

still returns `x` with a small imaginary component.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `Chop`, that's all.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate.  Could we please close it as such rather than "easily found in the documentation?"

Comment: Related: [(5235)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5235), [(17809)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17809),
[(52353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52353),
[(60278)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60278) - The last one seems the closest duplicate, but I'm surprised there isn't an older one.

Comment: I did search before asking, but couldn't find anything after a few tries.  `Chop` works, but I wouldn't say it's easy to find in the documentation unless you already know it's there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Chop[FindRoot[expr, {x, guess}]]
```